Cannot communicate over network with ROS in Windows Docker Container
I am trying to communicate between a ROS container running on a Windows 11 machine and a Raspberry Pi over a local network. I can see the topics but cannot see any data on the topic. I am pretty sure its a problem with the ROS_HOSTNAME or ROS_IP but I cannot get it working.
I am passing in ---net=host into the container
In the windows my IP address is 192.168.50.3
and in my Docker container I see two IP address:

eth0: 192.168.50.3
services1: 192.168.50.6

I am making the Windows ROS container the master by setting:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.50.3:11311
ROS_IP=192.168.50.3
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.50.3


Then on my PI I am setting:
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.50.136
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.50.3:11311


Based on everything I have read, this should work. I am pretty sure it has to do with some problem with the hostname or IP but I am not sure how to resolve the issue at this point.
